# Android App exits after choosing image from gallery

Tags: android, image

Here's the code:

```
package com.survey.sop;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class signup extends Activity 
{


   private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
   SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
   TextView name ;
   TextView address;
   TextView birthdate;
   TextView email;
   TextView username;
   TextView password;
   Button signup;
   ImageView imgAvatar;
   int id_To_Update = 0;



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.signup);

      name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
      address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);
      birthdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbdate);
      email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
      username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
      password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);
      signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
      imgAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);


      myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("surveyDB", MODE_PRIVATE,  null);

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      imgAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }

        });
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

   {

       public void onClick(View v)
       {


                    try

                    {
                      String usernameStr = username.getText().toString();
                      String passwordStr = password.getText().toString();
                      String nameStr = name.getText().toString();
                      String addressStr = address.getText().toString();
                      String birthdateStr = birthdate.getText().toString();


                      if (usernameStr.equals("") || passwordStr.equals("") || nameStr.equals("") || address.equals("") || birthdate.equals(""))

                      {
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please fill all the required fields.", 2).show();
                      }

                      else

                      {

                          myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users " + "(username, userpwd, name, address, birthdate, level)"
                          + " VALUES ('" + usernameStr + "', '" + passwordStr + "','"
                          + nameStr + "', '" + addressStr + "','"
                          + birthdateStr + "', 'user');");

                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully registered!", 2).show();

                            username.setText("");
                            password.setText("");
                            name.setText("");
                            address.setText("");
                            birthdate.setText("");
                      }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Error", "Error", e);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error signing up.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

       }

   });


   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
           {
           Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
           String s = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
    //testing
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, 4).show();
           }
   }


   private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);

   }


@Override
   protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
   }

}
```

What happens is that when I click the image, it opens the gallery where I can choose pictures.

I want to test if my codes can get the string of the selected image's directory so that I can store it/call it

from the database — unfortunately, after I choose an image, the app closes.

I don't know much about Android programming, still a new one.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the logcat :

```
06-26 15:18:56.218: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4
06-26 15:18:56.227: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
06-26 15:18:56.256: V/InputMethodManager(26324): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#8010500
06-26 15:18:56.256: V/InputMethodManager(26324): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42729b50 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,800} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4272e388 controlFlags=#104
06-26 15:18:56.259: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@4272ec18 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #1252}
06-26 15:18:56.295: I/InputMethodManager(26324): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE true, was false
06-26 15:18:59.298: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4
06-26 15:18:59.301: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
06-26 15:18:59.307: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Not IME target window, ignoring
06-26 15:18:59.327: V/InputMethodManager(26324): onWindowFocus: android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....ID 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#8010500
06-26 15:18:59.328: V/InputMethodManager(26324): START INPUT: android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....ID 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@4273ed18 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4273ec08 controlFlags=#107
06-26 15:18:59.331: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@4273f8f8 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #1253}
06-26 15:19:00.847: I/SurfaceTextureClient(26324): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x522866f0) fps:2.02, dur:1488.66, max:512.32, min:483.63
06-26 15:19:01.653: V/Provider/Settings(26324):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
06-26 15:19:01.654: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Not IME target window, ignoring
06-26 15:19:01.673: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Not IME target window, ignoring
06-26 15:19:01.704: V/InputMethodManager(26324): focusOut: android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....I. 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} mServedView=android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....I. 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} winFocus=false
06-26 15:19:02.352: I/SurfaceTextureClient(26324): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x522866f0) fps:1.99, dur:1505.53, max:617.73, min:387.83
06-26 15:19:02.357: V/InputMethodManager(26324): onWindowFocus: android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....ID 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#8010500
06-26 15:19:02.360: V/InputMethodManager(26324): focusOut: android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....ID 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} mServedView=android.widget.EditText{42736968 VFED..CL .F....ID 24,368-456,440 #7f080007 app:id/txtlUsername} winFocus=false
06-26 15:19:02.391: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4
06-26 15:19:02.395: V/PhoneWindow(26324): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
06-26 15:19:02.448: V/InputMethodManager(26324): onWindowFocus: android.widget.EditText{42750b90 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,203-480,275 #7f08000a app:id/txtname} softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#8010500
06-26 15:19:02.449: D/InputMethodManager(26324): deactivate the inputconnection in ControlledInputConnectionWrapper.
06-26 15:19:02.450: V/InputMethodManager(26324): START INPUT: android.widget.EditText{42750b90 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,203-480,275 #7f08000a app:id/txtname} ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@42762a48 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42762938 controlFlags=#107
06-26 15:19:02.452: V/InputMethodManager(26324): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@427635f0 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #1254}
06-26 15:19:03.417: V/Provider/Settings(26324):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
06-26 15:19:03.493: V/InputMethodManager(26324): focusOut: android.widget.EditText{42750b90 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,203-480,275 #7f08000a app:id/txtname} mServedView=android.widget.EditText{42750b90 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,203-480,275 #7f08000a app:id/txtname} winFocus=false
06-26 15:19:03.518: I/SurfaceTextureClient(26324): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52524000) fps:2.92, dur:1025.88, max:529.50, min:25.97
06-26 15:19:03.701: I/InputMethodManager(26324): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE false, was true
06-26 15:19:03.702: I/InputMethodManager(26324): handleMessage: MSG_UNBIND 1254
06-26 15:19:03.703: D/InputMethodManager(26324): deactivate the inputconnection in ControlledInputConnectionWrapper.
06-26 15:19:03.703: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26324): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Can you share the logcat output when it crashes?

Comment: Logcat doesn't display errors since I don't use emulator for testing. I think it has something to do with the Intent or like that.

Comment: you can even see the error while testing on device if you connect it to eclipse.

Comment: I updated my post now. TIA btw.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `onActivityResult()` is called, check the requestCode is valid.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE)
       {
           Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
           String s = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
           //testing
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, 4).show();
       }
   }
   ```
2. If your device memory isn't sufficient, you have to save some member variables which are used before calling `startActivityForResult`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       }
       else {
           // just sample member variables
           mOutputFileUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("mOutputFileUri", ""));
           mStep = savedInstanceState.getInt("mStep");
           mCropSizeX = savedInstanceState.getInt("mCropSizeX");
           mCropSizeY = savedInstanceState.getInt("mCropSizeY");
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putString("mOutputFileUri", (mOutputFileUri != null)? mOutputFileUri.toString(): "");
       outState.putInt("mStep", mStep);
       outState.putInt("mCropSizeX", mCropSizeX);
       outState.putInt("mCropSizeY", mCropSizeY);
   ```

   }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry. I don't have enough reputation to reply comment. I will edit this more specific.